# Drupal in Azure behind Loadmaster - HTTPS enforced no CSS

Tags: .htaccess

I bow to those who can help me out with this. I've done this with F5 before but for some reason this isn't working.

Drupal 7 sitting behind a Kemp LoadMaster, behind an Azure Load balancer. With Kemp redirecting from 80 to 443 and handling the ssl offload. I have tried every solution found and still the site loads partially with HTTPS, with most of the content trying to load through http.

https://demo.omegasys.eu is the site. Any help here is appreciated and I'm willing to post the config files if needed.

Comment: I have the following settings in htaccess and settings.php

htaccess:
 RewriteEngine on

       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)
       RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl:s]




settings.php:
$conf['reverse_proxy'] = TRUE;
$conf['reverse_proxy_addresses'] = array('10.0.0.10');


$conf['drupal_http_request_fails'] = FALSE;

$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = 443;